# How to make alertdialog on click to another activity

Tags: android, eclipse, android-alertdialog

I try to make alertdialog so that when clicked will display another activity, but that does not work. here's my code:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    final Entity_Brand brand = adapterBrand.getItem(position);

    CharSequence[] items = { "Cross Country(XC)", "All Mountain(AM)",
            "Free Ride(FR)", "DownHill(DH)", "DirtJump(DJ)", "Road Bike" };
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            Brand_ListView_Activity.this);
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_alert);
    builder.setTitle(brand.getNama_brand());
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            switch (item) {
            case 0:
                Toast.makeText(Brand_ListView_Activity.this,
                        R.layout.test, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

I realy realy need help. thank you so much :)

Comment: what u want to do is not clear from your question

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to create a [custom dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog)

Answer (score 1):

```
Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
d.setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
d.show();
```

Where this is referenced yo your activity